# Get results from mysql based on latitude longitude

Tags: php, mysql, select, latitude-longitude

I have a mysql Database and 2 tables let's say clients and schools. Now each table has columns latitude and longitude. And I need do make a SELECT for example from second table where schools are in a given radius of one record from first table. Calculations should be made based on latitude and longitude.
PS: I am using PHP.

Comment: In addition to Piskvor's answer, this tutorial is quite good: [Geo Distance Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL), although I found the page didn't load very well. As an alternative, the PowerPoint presentation can be found [here](http://www.mysqlconf.com/mysql2008/public/schedule/detail/347).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can calculate a distance using a [Spherical law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines):

```
SELECT DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(clients.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(schools.latitude)) + 
                    COS(RADIANS(clients.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(schools.latitude)) 
                                                   * COS(RADIANS(clients.longitude 
                                                               – schools.longitude)))) 
       * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 AS distance
FROM clients, schools HAVING distance < $radius
```

[RADIANS(X)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_radians) - degrees to radians
[ACOS(X)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_acos) - the arc cosine of X, that is, the value whose cosine is X
[DEGREES(X)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_degrees) - radians to degrees

60 - minutes in a degree
1.1515 - miles in a [nautical mile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_mile)
1.609344 - kilometres in a mile

Comment: So if my radius is in kilometers the query will be like you write or I should change it? thanks

Comment: Mysql gives an error : Unknown column 'clients.longitude–schools.longitude' in 'field list'..., what is the meaning of '-' sign here?