# How to select longitude, latitude around specifc location from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude around specific location. Actually I have some records (`longitude and latitude`) in mysql table. Now i want tofetch those longitude and latitude from table which should have around 500 meter of specific longitude. Please view the code, i hope you will understand my question.

### Mysql Location Table

```
-------------------------------------
id  |     longitude    |    latitude
-------------------------------------
1  |   25.058036      |    55.133467
-------------------------------------
2  |   25.056986      |    55.135755
-------------------------------------
3  |   25.059163       |   55.135616
-------------------------------------
4  |   25.056860       |  55.132515
-------------------------------------
5  |   25.055683       |   55.134792
```

I want to get those longitude, latitude which distance should have around 500 meters of specific (`25.057550, 55.134729`).

```
$user_long= $_REQUEST['user_long']; // 25.057550
$user_lat= $_REQUEST['user_lat']; // 55.134729

Select * from location where .... (fetch record around 500 meters)
```

I have searched about it and find some well expnained [haversine formula answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053358/measuring-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-php?answertab=active#tab-top) and [Google Map With Php/Mysql](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1#populating-the-table) but i did not got how can i develop this kind of functionality. I know this question may be stupid for someone because i'm not adding my code, but trust me i don't know how can i do it and from where i should start functionality. I will appreciate if someone guide me regarding this functionality.

Thank You

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get results from mysql based on latitude longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528754/get-results-from-mysql-based-on-latitude-longitude)

Comment: possible duplicate of [distance calculations in mysql queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986556/distance-calculations-in-mysql-queries)

Comment: possible duplicate of [select within 20 kilometers based on latitude/longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919661/select-within-20-kilometers-based-on-latitude-longitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((19.286558 - latitude)*pi()/180/2),2)+COS(19.286558 * pi()/180)
*COS(latitude * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((-99.612494 -longitude)* pi()/180/2),2)))
as distance FROM table  having distance < 10 ORDER BY distance;
```

This will give you records within 10 Km range.
modify query for 500 meters in having clause.

Comment: Thank you so much its working for me... I appreciate you

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
$query = "SELECT *,ROUND(1.609344*(((acos(sin((" . $latitude .    "*pi()/180)) * 
        sin((`Latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((" . $latitude . "*pi()/180)) * 
        cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((" . $longitude . "- `Longitude`)* 
        pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515
    ),2) as distance 
    FROM `table`  HAVING distance<=" . MAX_DISTANCE . " ";
```

where $latitude is user latitude and $longitude  is user longitude and MAX_DISTANCE is maximum distance you want to get that result in km.

Comment: Is your query relevant to the question content?

Comment: @BikashP Thanks for sharing knowledge, i'm not using store_type column in my table. Can you explain what is purpose of this table that i can check your query. Thanks a lot

Comment: updated my query. check it.I just removed where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *,
(6371*acos(cos(radians(" . $user_lat ."))*cos(radians(`latitude`))*cos(radians(`longitude`)-radians(" . $user_long . "))+sin(radians(" . $user_lat . "))*sin(radians(`latitude`)))) AS distance
FROM `location` WHERE `distance` < '0.5' ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

where 0.5 is in km

Answer (score 0):

If the performance of a custom implemented haversine formula will be too slow for you, and you don't mind using MySQL 5.7.6+, then you can leverage from build-in `ST_Distance_Sphere` function, which can be ±20times faster then custom implemented procedures for calculating haversine diestance. You can check the benchmarks and exmaples in this [blogpost](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/02/03/new-gis-features-in-mysql-5-7/). Also, if you don't mind storing your locations as `Point` geometry objects, you can also leverage from spatial indexes. Also you can first pre-filter locations based on bounding box (example in the end of [this blogpost](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-and-gis-an-example/)) which could also speed up the query.